# What would happen if an object were to pass through the center of a ringularity?

Tags: black-holes

A ringularity is [defined by Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ringularity) as a black hole with spin, that takes the shape of a ring with zero thickness. I know that the ergosphere imbues a lot of kinetic energy to objects that enter it, so what would happen if an object was to pass through the center of a ringularity in the direction perpendicular to the central plane of the ergosphere?

Comment: The issue is not so much the ergosphere as whether there is a infinite blueshift as it passes the different event horizons of the Kerr metric.